# Why does the method of substituting various trig functions in the angle of an inverse trig function to simplify/differentiate it work?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse, substitution

I have learnt that to simplify or to make differentiation of inverse trigonometric functions easier, you can simply substitute trigonometric functions in the angle for literally any sort of variable you want, so that you can express the angle as a trig identity, apply it, and thus simplify the function. Sure, it is effective. But why does it work? There must be some limitation on the type of variables you substitute, which I haven't seen yet. And, won't the simplification work for just that specific substitution only? How can it be generalised?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please, post only [one question in one post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7132/290189).
Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged
and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: You might start by giving some examples of what you’re asking about.

Comment: Alright, here's an inverse trigonometric function which we need to simplify. (apologies for the text, I am still a newbie trying to understand how to use MathJax)
tan^(-1)⁡〖(2x)/(1-x^2)〗
Let x = tan∅, hence ∅ = (tan^-1)x
=tan^(-1)⁡〖(2tan∅)/(1-tan^2⁡∅)〗
=tan^(-1)⁡〖(tan2∅)〗

=2∅=2 tan^(-1)⁡x

Comment: Compare differerntiations for $ \sin^{-1} x,\sin y$ separately. w.r.t. $x,y.$ Direct differetiation is better . why?